# Selecting Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas data-frame as a parameter table which is loaded in the beginning of my application run.

Structure of the csv that is being loaded into the data-frame is  as below :

```
param_name,param_value
source_dir,C:\Users\atiwari\Desktop\EDIFACT\source_dir
```

So the column names would be param_name and param_values.

How do i go about selecting the value from param_value where param_name == 'source_dir'?

I tried the below but it returns a data-frame with index not a string value:

```
param_df.loc[param_df['param_name']=='source_dir']['param_value']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It return `Series`:

```
s = param_df.loc[param_df['param_name']=='source_dir', 'param_value']
```

But if need `DataFrame`:

```
df = param_df.loc[param_df['param_name']=='source_dir', ['param_value']]
```

For scalar need convert Series by selecting by `[]` - select first value by `0`. Also works [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html).

[`Series.item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) need `Series` with values else get `error` if empty `Series`:

```
val = s.values[0]
```

---

```
val = s.iat[0]
```

---

```
val = s.item()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. But is there a way I can get it as String?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that worked. I will mark it as an answer.